# EXCEL SUM cells which contain string

Tags: string, excel, search, sum, formula

I'm trying to write a formula in Excel which will run down a column, and search each cell in that column for the presence of a string (which may be in the middle of another string); if the string is found, move over to another column and add the value in that cell to a running total.

Any gurus willing to help? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want a running total, or just the total? Either way you can use SUMIF with "wildcards"

For a simple total of all column B values where column A contains the substring "apple" try this formula

`=SUMIF(A:A,"*apple*",B:B)`

If you actually want a running total you can amend that to this version in C1 copied down:

`=SUMIF(A$1:A1,"*apple*",B$1:B1)`

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was after. Thanks Mr. Houdini!

Answer (score 1):

Say we want the running total of the cells in column **A** containing the work ***happy***.  In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"happy","")=A1,"",1)
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"happy","")=A2,"",1+MAX($B$1:B1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in `A1:A7` then you can use the CSE/Array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A7),A1:A7,0))
```

Enter the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter since this is an Array Formula.